# How do I do fast unit testing in a Rails app without loading the Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

In a Rails app, I would like to have a setup that allows me to run fast unit tests of Rails independent application logic.

Answer (score 0):

Have an alternative minimalistic test_helper.rb file where you just load minitest and make sure to require the code under test in your testcase file. That way you can run the test in isolation quickly and you can also run the test via Rake with the Rails environment loaded. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/peter/9596595) for a code example.

Answer (score 0):

There is explanation article about [spec_helper.rb](http://pivotallabs.com/spec-helper/?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email) for rspec. You can use it analog for unit tests, of course.